# How do I build a runnable JAR from a WebSphere Liberty / Open Liberty Maven WAR project?

Tags: maven, websphere, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I want to build a runnable/executable JAR (to run with `java -jar my.jar`), using Open Liberty, from my Maven WAR project.

If I run `mvn package` I get a WAR, but if I then run `mvn liberty:package` I get something like:

```
[INFO] CWWKM2001I: Invoke command is ["C:\git\lmparch1\test\target\liberty\wlp\bin\server.bat", package, defaultServer, --archive="C:\git\lmparch1\test\target\test.jar", --include=runnable].
[INFO] CWWKE0005E: The runtime environment could not be launched.
[INFO] CWWKE0031E: Specified defaultServer server does not exist; use the create action to create a new server. serverPath: C:\git\lmparch1\test\target\liberty\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.531 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-09T15:32:01-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.openliberty.tools:liberty-maven-plugin:3.3.4:package (default-cli) on project test: CWWKM2002E: Failed to invoke ["C:\git\lmparch1\test\target\liberty\wlp\bin\server.bat", package, defaultServer, --archive="C:\git\lmparch1\test\target\test.jar", --include=runnable]. RC= 2 but expected=[0]. -> [Help 1]
```

What goals am I supposed to configure and bind to which phases, etc. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you're using the **liberty-maven-app-parent** to set up your lifecycle (or similarly binding goals to phases on your own), vs. using something closer to the built-in war lifecycle bindings (without all the extra 'liberty' plugin goal bindings).

### Using Liberty Maven app parent (or similar)

First, if you're using the [io.openliberty.tools:liberty-maven-app-parent](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/blob/master/liberty-maven-app-parent/pom.xml), e.g. from generating with the [liberty-archetype-webapp](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven#liberty-archetype-webapp)_  then you simply need to use this as your liberty-maven-plugin configuration:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <include>minify,runnable</include>
```

and do `mvn package`.

You'll see the runnable JAR created as something like: **target/xyz.jar**

### Using generic WAR project interactively

The simplest way to do this is to let dev mode install Liberty and package and deploy the WAR, then `Ctrl+C` cancel out of it to package the runnable JAR.

1. Run `mvn liberty:dev` to launch ["dev mode"](https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/10/22/liberty-dev-mode.html) and wait for the server install and app deploy
2. Type `<Ctrl+C>` when dev mode completes startup (either when you see *Liberty is running in dev mode* or once you see the app started **CWWKT0016I** application available message).
3. Run `mvn liberty:package -Dinclude=minify,runnable` to generate the runnable JAR (something like: **target/xyz.jar**).

### Using generic WAR project in a CI env (e.g. build pipeline)

If you're running non-interactively, where issuing the `Ctrl+C` isn't easy, you could do

`mvn package liberty:create liberty:install-feature liberty:deploy liberty:package -Dinclude=minify,runnable`

We have opened [this issue](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues/739) to consider improving this use case.